# how to trigger click button?

Tags: jquery

I have this click button code

```
    \$("#extractmonkeys").click(function () {
        \$("#grapharea").html(" ");
        \$("#paramselection").html(" ");
```

How can I trigger this code from somewhere else?

```
     \$("#extractmonkeys").trigger("click");
```

Am i missing something?

please note: \$ is because i'm coding jquery inside perl ...

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you know that the click event handler isn't closed? (Or did you forget to copy&paste the whole block?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction(){
```

`$("#grapharea").html(" ");`
 `$("#paramselection").html(" ");`

`}`

`$("#extractmonkeys").click(function () {`

`myFunction();`

`}`

this way you can call your function from everywere

Answer (score 1):

That code should work fine.
You can also call `$(...).click()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `});` from the end of:

```
\$("#extractmonkeys").click(function () {
    \$("#grapharea").html(" ");
    \$("#paramselection").html(" ");
```

Otherwise, your `\$("#extractmonkeys").trigger("click");` will work.

It could also be possible that the above code is not inside a document.ready:

```
\$(document).ready(function () {
    /* code here */
});
```

In which case "#extractmonkeys" cannot be found and thus nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what's wrong

- Check the source of the web page to make sure your code is there
- Check the resources with fiddler, ... to make sure your jQuery script is loaded and has not got 404
- Use javascript console in Chrome, etc to call that function and make sure it can be called
- put an alert in your function. Perhaps it is being called but does not produce the result you want.